# Javascript function call from silverlight in MSCRM 2016 turbo forms

Tags: javascript, silverlight, legacy, dynamics-crm-2016

I am trying to call a javascript function "myFunction" which is in the namespace "quote.Controller" which is loaded on Quote form. I am trying to create an instance as below

`ScriptObject result=HtmlPage.Window.CreateInstance("quote.Controller");`

Above line works fine when I set "Use legacy form rendering" to Yes in MSCRM 2016. But if i set "Use legacy form rendering" to No, I am getting an exception "Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application Type 'quote.Controller' does not exist.". It might be because Silverlight control is unable to find the javascript file on the form. I tried the below code

```
var parent = HtmlPage.Window.GetProperty("parent") as HtmlWindow;
if (parent != null)
{
     parent.CreateInstance("quote.Controller");
}
```

No luck with the above code block.
Any suggestion on what could be the issue?

Comment: Not sure, but I think when using Turbo Forms, there are a lot of `iFrames` added to the page, depending on which frame you're in, you may have access to different scopes. Like I said, not sure if this is the cause of your problem

Comment: I tried finding my custom javascript code in DOM explorer, but couldn't find it on turbo form. But if i set "Use legacy form rendering" to Yes, i am able to find the custom code in DOM.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's because your js code might be in a different frame

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the file that contains your js function.

I mean you have to add the library that contains your function via the form properties.